# PHP PDO duplicate row on insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I'm running into an issue with PHP's PDO on insert queries.

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And am using the following code

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db", "user", "pass");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`col1`) VALUE ('test_val')");
$stmt->execute();
```

By running this code I expect to get 1 new row, but instead two are inserting with the same value! The `id` field is incremented for each of the two rows.

All other queries such as SELECT, DELETE complex queries with multiple nested joins, and binding parameters seem to work fine, they all fetch the data they are supposed to. The issue only seems to be with the insert queries.

I've searched around a bit and couldn't find any documentation on this issue. I'm curious if there is a flag or option I'm missing that is causing this behavior.

Note: I've been using PDO for a large project for the past few years, this code is part of a wrapper that I have used successfully for that time. I just set up a new VM and forked the old project to begin work on a new version, which is where I noticed this issue. I've narrowed it down to those three lines and made the `test` table to test the issue.

Environment:

- Newly formatted Debian 8.7 VM
- Using MariaDB: 10.0.28-MariaDB-0+deb8u1 (Debian)
- Using Apache: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
- Using PHP: 5.6.29-0+deb8u1 (built: Dec 13 2016 16:02:08)

Perhaps a bug with PHP or mysql?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bug in your code

Comment: Seems like you execute code two times? Maybe you have ajax call that is executed two times?

Comment: There are no ajax calls that I am aware of, I made a new index.php with just that code in it, nothing else, and am loading it with chrome. I profiled the code with Xdebug and did not see any duplicate calls.